# Convert .mp3 file to .wav or .caf in code in iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I am retrieving an MP3 file from the iPod Library and saving it to the application's Documents directory. I need to convert it to .wav or .caf so that I can use OpenAL or any other library to change the pitch of the audio.

Can this be done? Any assistance with code will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the AVAssetWriter class. Also, check out this link, its not exactly what you want, but its a start.

http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/

Note that it might be difficult to gain access to the user's actual file as that would require reaching out of your app's sandbox - something Apple doesn't allow.

Comment: Hello if I have file of .caf format is it possible to convert it into .mp3? The .caf file is in the NSDocumentsDirectory of the application. So accessing is never an issue.